# Can't remove default Debug and Release configurations from ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created a new ASP.NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2015, and when I try to remove the default Debug or Release project build configurations, I get the message:

"The 'Debug' and 'Release configurations are always supported and can't be removed."

[image: Error message]

Why is this? I can do this with a regular/full ASP.NET web application project.